# Putting PHP objects to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I need a JS array of PHP arrays, specifically formatted, like this:

```
products = [{}, {}, {}]
```

I have been google for 2 days and trying to use php function json_encode, but it doesn't give me format I'm looking for.
I'm getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3971
            [name] => Test
            [price] => 1107.9000
            [brand] => KM
            [variant] => 
            [quantity] => 3.27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3957
            [name] => Test
            [price] => 87.3000
            [brand] => KM
            [variant] => 
            [quantity] => 4
        )    
)
```

Sorry for dumb duplicated question.

Comment: use **json_encode** and read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: When you use `json_encode()`, you do not get what you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your javascript via php:

```
<script>
var foo = <?php echo json_encode(["foo"=>"bar"]); ?>;
</script>
```

obtaining

```
<script>
var foo = {"foo":"bar"};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, sensorario!